# How to make elasticsearch an efficent search engine?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, search-engine, kibana, bitnami

Can some one please provide the points that one may consider while making elasticsearch search engine efficient? 
The experience of the developers making the search engine faster and efficient would help new developers like me to make the elasticsearch more reliable.

If the question looks irrelevant please let me know, I will modify it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Here are a few good reads on the subject: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html + https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html + https://qbox.io/blog/authoritative-guide-elasticsearch-performance-tuning-part-1

Comment: thanks, the third link is the kind of link i was looking for.
It will serve my purpose.